# Trying to destroy request via ajax for relationship entities in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to delete a "budget"(in portuguese, "orçamento") via ajax request, and that budgets have a relationship belongs to cadastre and cadastre has many budgets. My components are as follows:

#### orcamentos_controller.rb

```
.
.
.

    def destroy
            @cadastro = Cadastro.find(params[:cadastro_id])
            @orcamento = @cadastro.orcamentos.find(params[:orcamento_id])
            @orcamento.destroy

            respond_to do |format|
                format.js { head :ok }
            end
    end

    def index
        @cadastro = Cadastro.find(params[:cadastro_id])
        @orcamentos = @cadastro.orcamentos.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
.
.
.
```

#### index.html.erb

```
... <%= render "orcamentos_lista" %> ...
```

#### _orcamentos_lista.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
    <% @orcamentos.each do |orcamento| %>
      <tr id="remove_orcamento_<%= orcamento.id %>">
          <td>
              <%= link_to "Orçamento nº #{orcamento.id}, registrado em #{orcamento.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}", "#", class: "list-group-item", type: 'button'%>
          </td>
          <td>
              <%= link_to "Excluir", orcamento, method: :destroy, remote: true %>
          </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>

<% content_for :js do %>
  <% @orcamentos.each do |orcamento| %>
    $('#remove_orcamento_<%= orcamento.id %>').bind('ajax:success',
     function(){
       $('#orcamento_<%=orcamento.id%>').remove();
     }
    );
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### routes.rb

```
.
.
.
    resources :cadastros do
      resources :orcamentos
    end
.
.
.
```

I get the error `undefined method orcamento_path for #<#<Class:0x007f5f39757930>:0x007f5f39cf1eb8>` this line `<%= link_to "Excluir", orcamento, method: :destroy, remote: true %>`

I am a beginner in both ruby as on rails, so forgive me any ugliness in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
rake routes
```

Then whatever path you want that link to have in it find it in the table of routes and use the 'prefix' for it with "_path" at the end. So if the resource you want is on that table and has a prefix of `foo_bar` then your link_to should have `foo_bar_path` used in your view.

so change this line

```
<%= link_to "Excluir", orcamento, method: :destroy, remote: true %>
```

to this

```
<%= link_to "Excluir", foo_bar_path, method: :destroy, remote: true %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I get other error: `undefined local variable or method orcamento_path for #<#<Class:0x007f5f39757930>:0x007f5f3a47d1a0>`

Comment: This is the route: 
`resources :cadastros do
      resources :orcamentos
    end`

Comment: run `rake routes` in terminal and then whatever path you want that link to have in it find it in the table of routes and you use the 'prefix' for it + _path. So if the resource you want is on that table and has a prefix of foo_bar then your link_to should have foo_bar_path on it

Comment: That helped me solve this problem, I changed `orcamento` for `cadastro_orcamento_path`. Only I get another problem now, `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Orcamentos#index` and `No route matches {:action=>"show", :cadastro_id=>"3", :controller=>"orcamentos"} missing required keys: [:id]`. It seems to be a problem with the id :(

Comment: I've updated my answer. Give me a :up_vote plz as it got you past the error you posted here. Also this last comment the problem is that your using :cadastro_id=>3 when it seems to be wanting :id=>3 instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're calling `orcamento` as the link, when you've nested it within `cadastros`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cadastros do
   resources :orcamentos # -> url.com/cadastros/:catastros_id/orcamentos/:id
end
```

This means if you want to call the path helper for an `orcamentos`, you have to use the nested resource:

```
cadastros_orcamentos_path(@cadastros, orcamento)
```

If you're using `link_to`, you should be able to pass an array of the nested objects as you require:

```
link_to "Delete", [@cadastros, orcamento], method: :delete
```